# print nested map in java without using instanceof operator

Tags: java

I have a map of string Object:

```
Map<String, Object> someMap
```

The map can contain as a value list, map, null, String or any other value.

I would like to print my map as one flat map.

For example:

input map:

> {"a":"a1","b":"b1","c":"c1",
>   "d":{"e":"e1","f":{"g":"g1"},"h":"h1"},"i":"i1","j":[{"k":"k1"},{"l":"l1"}],"m":"m1","n":null}

---

Output String:

> "a="a1" b="b1" c="c1" e="e1" g="g1" h="h1" i="i1" k="k1" l="l1"
>   m="m1""

Is there a way to do so without using `instanceof` for handling the different Objects?

Comment: What's wrong with `instanceOf`?

Comment: instanceOf is wasteful, I am trying to find a more effectual way.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for.
Per definition each `Object` has to implement `toString()`.
There is only one special case: `toString` leads to a `NullPointerException` for a `null` value.

```
@Test
public void testId(){
    Map<String, Object> someMap = new HashMap<>();
    someMap.put("1", null);
    someMap.put("2", asList(1,2,3,4));
    someMap.put("3", 3);
    someMap.put("4", "Hello World! Greetings from Germany <3");

    someMap.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null)
            .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey()
                    .concat("=")
                    .concat(entry.getValue().toString())));
}
```

leads to:

```
2=[1, 2, 3, 4]
3=3
4=Hello World! Greetings from Germany <3
```

a `null` value will be filtered in this case!

Comment: this is a good idea, but not exactly what I am looking for. in your example the string I would like it to be: 2="1, 2, 3, 4" 3="3" 4="Hello World"

Comment: yes and you can reach that with some small changes based on my code.

Comment: but if we will add Map<String, String> someMapValue = new HashMap<>();someMapValue.put("Hi","Hi :) and Thanks") and we will add it to the map someMap.put("5",someMapValue) the output will be:  "2=[1, 2, 3, 4] 3=3 4=Hello World! Greetings from Germany <3 5={Hi="Hi :) and Thanks}" and I trying to get: "2=[1, 2, 3, 4] 3=3 4=Hello World! Greetings from Germany <3 Hi="Hi :) and Thanks"